# Sitecore Commerce Categories children is not being populated. "GetNavigationViewModel"

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-commerce

I have setup Sitecore 8.2 + Commerce Server + SOLR

I have created Catalog under departments. "Commerce Catalog Manager"

**[Commerce Catalog Manager]**

- ABC (category)

  - ZYX (sub Category)

    - ZZZ (sub Category)

      - product A
      - product b
  - DDD

    - ABC

      - product c
      - product d

Below is the code snippet i am using.

```
Item item = base.Item.Database.GetItem(str);
Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Models.SitecoreItemModels.Category category = this.CatalogManager.GetCategory(item);
NavigationViewModel navigationViewModel = this.GetNavigationViewModel(category.InnerItem, base.CurrentRendering);
```

**Question**

Why i always get navigationViewModel.ChildrenCategories count 0?

Is there any more steps i should take care?

Is there any better way, if i don't want solr index/Good way to use Solr but avoid re-index? Because every time when we create product, we have to rebuild index and clear site cache.

**Tried Approaches**

I already tried below approaches..

I republished entire site + Rebuild Solr Index "sitecore_core_index, sitecore_master_index, sitecore_web_index, commerce_products_master_index, commerce_userprofiles_index_master, commerce_products_web_index"

I have also cleared related cache using 
http://[Domain]/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx

Comment: We would need to see the code for `this.GetNavigationViewModel` to be able to help you. Also; sounds like you have some configuration errors - your indexes should update automatically without requiring a full rebuild - this could be the root cause.

Comment: Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Controllers.CatalogController has method GetNavigationViewModel. It is provided by Sitecore only. Related to index i have tried so many time but could not find the root cause. Please suggest way to find it.